# Windows - Make CMD.exe To Autoclose After Starting Application

Tags: node.js, windows, powershell, cmd, visual-studio-code

File `a.bat`:-

```
start powershell "npm init"
code .
```

When I double click the above file, it opens a powershell window with the `npm init` command executed in it and it also opens `visual studio code` with current directory opened in it. cmd.exe exits after this. But for the following bat file:-

```
start /min powershell "gulp scss; gulp watch-scss;"
start /min powershell "gulp js; gulp watch-js;"
start /min powershell "http-server;"
code .
```

when I double click it, everything happens as it should except that cmd.exe does not exits and stays open in the waiting state (as it is waiting for visual studio code to close.)

How can I make cmd.exe to exit when all the commands have been executed (like in the case of `a.bat`)?

**Update**

The batch file does not keep cmd.exe opened if I omit the last line `code .`. The following batch file works perfectly fine:-

```
start /min powershell "gulp scss; gulp watch-scss;"
start /min powershell "gulp js; gulp watch-js;"
start /min powershell "http-server;"
```

The problem starts when I add the line `code .`

Comment: Well it looks like you are not showing us all your code so how can we really determine a solution?  Also, I am not understanding the use of Powershell in this instance.

Comment: Try `start code .` instead.

Comment: @Squashman These are complete `bat` files. Nothing is hidden. Using powershell to execute gulp and npm http-server is my personal preference and it works well.

Comment: @dxiv Well, using `start code .` doesn't keep the cmd.exe in waiting state but it doesn't close it.

Comment: @OmarTariq `doesn't keep the cmd.exe in waiting state but it doesn't close it` So it just returns to the prompt? You could add an `exit` line at the end of the file, though normally that shouldn't be needed if you start the batch file by double-clicking.

Comment: @dxiv Yes, it returns to prompt. No luck with `exit`. I've tried many other .bat files that opens Powershell and other applications and all of them closes cmd.exe at the end of the script. The problem is very specific to this bat file.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing these

```
start "" /min powershell "gulp scss; gulp watch-scss;"
start "" /min powershell "gulp js; gulp watch-js;"
start "" /min powershell "http-server;"
code .
```

or if youre running a powershell file, use this

```
Powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File  location\to\ps\file.ps
```

Comment: This keeps the cmd.exe in the waiting state, as if it is waiting for vscode to close. I've updated my question with some more useful information. Thanks.

Comment: @OmarTariq Ive never someone use 'code .' before in bat files. Can you explain what the code . is?

Comment: I'm a lazy man. `right-click -> open with code` takes too much time. Why not put it in a bat file which auto resumes everything related to my project?

Comment: No, your does not closes cmd.exe after the execution of the batch file. It puts it in the waiting state.

Comment: @OmarTariq Try adding **exit** at the end of the batch file.